# nginx & php-fpm [debug] 11: Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: nginx, php

*New Development*

The core php error logs are below, but the site specific error logs show this. The memory on my php.ini file is :

memory_size 1024;

so it's not php's memory limit. I've also disabled all my plugin's, so it's not the memory limit that is on my security plugin.

2014/12/13 16:12:40 [error] 28264#0: *212 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 71 bytes) in /var/www/..

---

I am having troubles with a wordpress plugin running a full batch of imports. I get this error when I enable the nginx debug. The result is I get an immediate 404 error afterwards and I am unable to fully import my data.

I am pretty sure this is a bug, but I can't find the right answer to fix it.

Please Help.

**What I have done so far:**

- It looked like a nginx bug and my nginx version was old, so I upgraded. No change.
- It looked and still looks like it could be related to php-fpm. I've upgraded. No change.
- I've disabled all of my plugins. No Change.

**Server**

- CentOS 6.0
- nginx v 1.0.15
- PHP-FPM v 5.3.3 (fpm-fcgi)
- Webserver running 3 very low traffic sites
- PHP-FPM is set to ondemmand

**PHP.ini config:**

- pm = ondemand
- pm.process_idle_timeout = 50s
- pm.max_children = 20
- pm.start_servers = 1
- pm.min_spare_servers = 3
- pm.max_spare_servers = 5
- pm.max_requests = 1024
- pm.status_path = /status

I am unable to post my logs, so please check out the comparison

**Nginx Log:**

```
[12-Dec-2014 06:35:49.398315] DEBUG: pid 13384, fpm_pctl_perform_idle_server_maintenance(), line 362: [pool www] currently 0 active children, 1 spare children
[12-Dec-2014 06:35:50.399474] DEBUG: pid 13384, fpm_pctl_perform_idle_server_maintenance(), line 362: [pool www] currently 0 active children, 1 spare children
[12-Dec-2014 06:35:51.400765] DEBUG: pid 13384, fpm_pctl_perform_idle_server_maintenance(), line 362: [pool www] currently 0 active children, 1 spare children
[12-Dec-2014 06:35:52.402053] DEBUG: pid 13384, fpm_pctl_perform_idle_server_maintenance(), line 362: [pool www] currently 0 active children, 1 spare children
[12-Dec-2014 06:35:53.403346] DEBUG: pid 13384, fpm_pctl_perform_idle_server_maintenance(), line 362: [pool www] currently 0 active children, 1 spare children
[12-Dec-2014 06:35:53.417762] DEBUG: pid 13384, fpm_got_signal(), line 72: received SIGCHLD
[12-Dec-2014 06:35:53.417836] DEBUG: pid 13384, fpm_children_bury(), line 254: [pool www] child 18327 has been killed by the process managment after 52.123053 seconds from start
[12-Dec-2014 06:35:53.417863] DEBUG: pid 13384, fpm_event_loop(), line 411: event module triggered 1 events
[12-Dec-2014 06:35:54.404978] DEBUG: pid 13384, fpm_pctl_perform_idle_server_maintenance(), line 362: [pool www] currently 0 active children, 0 spare children
[12-Dec-2014 06:35:54.687559] DEBUG: pid 13384, fpm_children_make(), line 421: [pool www] child 18397 started




[12-Dec-2014 06:35:54.687593] DEBUG: pid 13384, fpm_pctl_on_socket_accept(), line 536: [pool www] got accept without idle child available .... I forked
[12-Dec-2014 06:35:54.687602] DEBUG: pid 13384, fpm_event_loop(), line 411: event module triggered 1 events




[12-Dec-2014 06:35:55.406455] DEBUG: pid 13384, fpm_pctl_perform_idle_server_maintenance(), line 362: [pool www] currently 0 active children, 1 spare children
[12-Dec-2014 06:35:56.407633] DEBUG: pid 13384, fpm_pctl_perform_idle_server_maintenance(), line 362: [pool www] currently 0 active children, 1 spare children
[12-Dec-2014 06:35:57.408949] DEBUG: pid 13384, fpm_pctl_perform_idle_server_maintenance(), line 362: [pool www] currently 0 active children, 1 spare children
[12-Dec-2014 06:35:58.410111] DEBUG: pid 13384, fpm_pctl_perform_idle_server_maintenance(), line 362: [pool www] currently 0 active children, 1 spare children
```

**PHP log:**

```
2014/12/12 06:35:02 [debug] 13350#0: *223 http header done
2014/12/12 06:35:54 [debug] 13350#0: accept on 0.0.0.0:80, ready: 1
2014/12/12 06:35:54 [debug] 13350#0: posix_memalign: 0000000002273A80:256 @16
2014/12/12 06:35:54 [debug] 13350#0: *226 accept: 66.249.67.123 fd:3
2014/12/12 06:35:54 [debug] 13350#0: *226 event timer add: 3: 60000:1418387814684
2014/12/12 06:35:54 [debug] 13350#0: *226 epoll add event: fd:3 op:1 ev:80000001
2014/12/12 06:35:54 [debug] 13350#0: accept() not ready (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
2014/12/12 06:35:54 [debug] 13350#0: *226 malloc: 0000000002274AF0:1296
2014/12/12 06:35:54 [debug] 13350#0: *226 posix_memalign: 0000000002273BE0:256 @16
2014/12/12 06:35:54 [debug] 13350#0: *226 malloc: 000000000232F4B0:131072
2014/12/12 06:35:54 [debug] 13350#0: *226 posix_memalign: 00000000021F7590:4096 @16
2014/12/12 06:35:54 [debug] 13350#0: *226 http process request line
2014/12/12 06:35:54 [debug] 13350#0: *226 recv: fd:3 315 of 131072
2014/12/12 06:35:54 [debug] 13350#0: *226 http request line: "GET /stores/giltcity/page/78/ HTTP/1.1"
2014/12/12 06:35:54 [debug] 13350#0: *226 http uri: "/stores/giltcity/page/78/"
2014/12/12 06:35:54 [debug] 13350#0: *226 http args: ""
2014/12/12 06:35:54 [debug] 13350#0: *226 http exten: ""
2014/12/12 06:35:54 [debug] 13350#0: *226 http process request header line
2014/12/12 06:35:54 [debug] 13350#0: *226 http header: "Host: mydiscountman.com"
2014/12/12 06:35:54 [debug] 13350#0: *226 http header: "Connection: Keep-alive"
2014/12/12 06:35:54 [debug] 13350#0: *226 http header: "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
2014/12/12 06:35:54 [debug] 13350#0: *226 http header: "From: googlebot(at)googlebot.com"
2014/12/12 06:35:54 [debug] 13350#0: *226 http header: "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate"
2014/12/12 06:35:54 [debug] 13350#0: *226 http header: "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
2014/12/12 06:35:54 [debug] 13350#0: *226 http header done
2014/12/12 06:37:11 [debug] 13350#0: accept on 0.0.0.0:80, ready: 1
```

**Nginx Global Config /etc/nginx/nginx.conf :**

```
user apache;
worker_processes 1;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
worker_connections 768;
multi_accept on;
use epoll;
}

http {

# Let NGINX get the real client IP for its access logs
set_real_ip_from 127.0.0.1;
real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;

# Basic Settings
sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 20;
client_max_body_size 15m;
client_body_timeout 60;
client_header_timeout 60;
client_body_buffer_size  128k;
client_header_buffer_size 128k;
large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;
send_timeout 60;
reset_timedout_connection on;
types_hash_max_size 8192;
server_tokens off;

# server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
# server_name_in_redirect off;

include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

# Logging Settings
# access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;

# Log Format
log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
'"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
'"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

# Gzip Settings
gzip on;
gzip_static on;
gzip_disable "msie6";
gzip_vary on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_min_length 512;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_types text/css text/javascript text/xml text/plain text/x-component 
application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json 
application/xml  application/rss+xml font/truetype application/x-font-ttf 
font/opentype application/vnd.ms-fontobject image/svg+xml;

# Virtual Host Configs
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

**Nginx Site Config /etc/nginx/sites-available/testme  :**

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name  testme.XXXXXXX.com;

port_in_redirect off;
server_tokens off;
autoindex off;

client_max_body_size 15m;
client_body_buffer_size 128k;

access_log  /var/log/nginx/testme/access_log  main;
error_log   /var/log/nginx/testme/error_log;

root /var/www/testme;
index index.php  index.html index.htm;
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;

error_page  404              /404error.html;
location = /var/www/testme/404error.html {
    internal;
}

error_page  500              /500error.html;
location = /var/www/testme/500error.html {
    internal;
}

# Define default caching of 24h
expires 8s;
add_header Pragma public;
add_header Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";

# Redirect server error pages to static 50x.html
error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

# Don't log robots.txt requests
location = /robots.txt {
    allow all;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}

location /phpmyadmin {
auth_basic            "Restricted";
auth_basic_user_file  /var/www/testme/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd;
try_files $uri $uri/ index.html index.php;
index index.html index.htm index.php;
location ~ /\.ht {
    deny  all;
}
location ~* ^.+\.(css|js)$ {
    #try_files $uri $uri/;
    #root /var/www/testme/phpmyadmin;
    access_log off;
}
location ~ ^.+\.php {
    try_files $uri $uri/ *.php;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+.php)(.*)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.socket;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/testme$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_ignore_client_abort off;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 180;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;

}
}

# Rewrite for versioned CSS+JS via filemtime
#    location ~* ^.+\.(css|js) {
#        rewrite ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(css|js)$ $1.$3 last;
#        expires 31536000s;
#        access_log on;
#        log_not_found on;
#        add_header Pragma public;
#        add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public";
#    }

# Aggressive caching for static files
# If you alter static files often, please use 
# add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
location ~* \.    (asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|eot|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|ogv|otf|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|svg|svgz|swf|tar|t?gz|tif|tiff|ttf|wav|webm|wma|woff|wri|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip)$ {
    expires 31536000s;
    access_log on;
    log_not_found on;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public";
}


location ~* (^(?!(?:(?!(php|inc)).)*/uploads/).*?(php)) {
set $php_root   $document_root;
    if ($request_uri ~* /phpmyadmin) {
    #set $php_root /usr/share;
    }

    try_files $uri = 404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+.php)(.*)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.socket;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $php_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_ignore_client_abort off;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 3600;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 3600;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 3600;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
    fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
  }

}
```

**PHP.ini**

```
    [PHP]

    ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
    ; Quick Reference ;
    ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

    error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE

    extension=apc.so

    ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
    ; Language Options ;
    ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

    engine = On
    short_open_tag = Off
    asp_tags = Off
    precision = 14
    y2k_compliance = On
    zlib.output_compression = Off
    implicit_flush = Off
    unserialize_callback_func =
    serialize_precision = 100

    safe_mode = Off
    safe_mode_gid = Off
    safe_mode_include_dir =
    safe_mode_exec_dir =
    safe_mode_allowed_env_vars = PHP_
    safe_mode_protected_env_vars = LD_LIBRARY_PATH
    disable_functions =
    disable_classes =
    realpath_cache_size = 16k
    realpath_cache_ttl = 120

    ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
    ; Miscellaneous ;
    ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

    expose_php = On

    ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
    ; Resource Limits ;
    ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

    max_execution_time = 600
    set_time_limit = 600
    max_input_time = 300
    memory_limit = 2048M

    ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
    ; Error handling and logging ;
    ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

    error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
    display_errors = Off
    display_startup_errors = Off
    log_errors = On
    log_errors_max_len = 1024
    ignore_repeated_errors = Off
    ignore_repeated_source = Off
    report_memleaks = On
    track_errors = Off
    html_errors = Off
    error_log = /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log


    ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
    ; Data Handling ;
    ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

    variables_order = "GPCS"
    request_order = "GP"
    register_globals = Off
    register_long_arrays = Off
    register_argc_argv = Off
    auto_globals_jit = On
    post_max_size = 384M
    magic_quotes_gpc = Off
    magic_quotes_runtime = Off
    magic_quotes_sybase = Off
    auto_prepend_file =
    auto_append_file =
    default_mimetype = "text/html"

    ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
    ; Paths and Directories ;
    ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

    doc_root =
    user_dir =
    enable_dl = Off
    cgi.fix_pathinfo=0

    ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
    ; File Uploads ;
    ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

    file_uploads = On
    upload_max_filesize = 512M

    ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
    ; Fopen wrappers ;
    ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

    allow_url_fopen = On
    allow_url_include = Off
    default_socket_timeout = 120

    ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
    ; Dynamic Extensions ;
    ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

    ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
    ; Module Settings ;
    ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

    [Date]

    date.timezone = America/Chicago

    [filter]

    [iconv]

    [intl]

    [sqlite]

    [sqlite3]

    [Pcre]

    [Pdo]

    [Phar]

    [Syslog]

    define_syslog_variables  = Off

    [mail function]

    SMTP = localhost
    smtp_port = 25
    sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
    mail.add_x_header = On

    [SQL]

    sql.safe_mode = Off

    [ODBC]

    odbc.allow_persistent = On
    odbc.check_persistent = On
    odbc.max_persistent = -1
    odbc.max_links = -1
    odbc.defaultlrl = 4096
    odbc.defaultbinmode = 1

    [MySQL]

    mysql.allow_persistent = On
    mysql.max_persistent = -1
    mysql.max_links = -1
    mysql.default_port =
    mysql.default_socket =
    mysql.default_host =
    mysql.default_user =
    mysql.default_password =
    mysql.connect_timeout = 300
    mysql.trace_mode = Off

    [MySQLi]

    mysqli.max_links = -1
    mysqli.default_port = 3306
    mysqli.default_socket =
    mysqli.default_host =
    mysqli.default_user =
    mysqli.default_pw =
    mysqli.reconnect = Off

    [PostgresSQL]

    pgsql.allow_persistent = On
    pgsql.auto_reset_persistent = Off
    pgsql.max_persistent = -1
    pgsql.max_links = -1
    pgsql.ignore_notice = 0
    pgsql.log_notice = 0

    [Sybase-CT]

    sybct.allow_persistent = On
    sybct.max_persistent = -1
    sybct.max_links = -1
    sybct.min_server_severity = 10
    sybct.min_client_severity = 10

    [bcmath]

    bcmath.scale = 0

    [browscap]

    [Session]

    session.save_handler = files
    session.save_path = "/var/lib/php/session"
    session.use_cookies = 1
    session.use_only_cookies = 1
    session.name = PHPSESSID
    session.auto_start = 0
    session.cookie_lifetime = 0
    session.cookie_path = /
    session.cookie_domain =
    session.cookie_httponly = 
    session.serialize_handler = php
    session.gc_probability = 1
    session.gc_divisor = 1000
    session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
    session.bug_compat_42 = Off
    session.bug_compat_warn = Off
    session.referer_check =
    session.entropy_length = 0
    session.entropy_file =
    session.cache_limiter = nocache
    session.cache_expire = 180
    session.use_trans_sid = 0
    session.hash_function = 0
    session.hash_bits_per_character = 5
    url_rewriter.tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry"

    [MSSQL]

    mssql.allow_persistent = On
    mssql.max_persistent = -1
    mssql.max_links = -1
    mssql.min_error_severity = 10
    mssql.min_message_severity = 10
    mssql.compatability_mode = Off
    mssql.timeout = 300
    mssql.secure_connection = Off




    [Tidy]

    tidy.clean_output = Off

    [soap]

    soap.wsdl_cache_enabled=1
    soap.wsdl_cache_dir="/tmp"
    soap.wsdl_cache_ttl=86400
```

Comment: so, the forking command is not a bug. The PHP process stopping 100% due to the child being killed is the fundamental problem.

Why or how I am still unsure. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: memory_size 1024; means 1024 bytes.

Comment: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 71 bytes) - it's really PHP memory limit, so check your settings (use phpinfo() command)

Comment: my PHP memory_limit was already at 2048M. I have posted my php.ini file on the question.

Comment: do you checked memory limit throw phpinfo()? Better in place close to error place.

Comment: Looks like if I disable my security plugin, then the error does not occur, but I still get the 500 error. Looks like my initial issue is related to the import plugin.

Comment: I disabled all my plugins and re-enabled them one at a time. My issue is resolved, but all of my plugins are re-enabled. Really bizarre.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the code PHP enforcement at that moment, and should optimize the command PHP that causes a buffer overflow. Rather than increasing the memory limit execute commands on your code.

Because my company have somethings cases error as you. At first, I increase memory for dev, but after we realize that should not increase the memory up that should perform optimally on code. When its help you improve in programming.